# How to filter email with base 64 encoding using procmail

Tags: mysql, email, ubuntu, procmail

I am trying to filter email with base 64 encoding, then decode the message body, then pass it for further filtering, but it won't find a match on the type of email from header, I tried Content-Transfer-Encoding and Content-Type, but no match are found from the header.
Here is the procmailrc I configured:

```
DEFAULT=/var/mail/
LOGFILE=$HOME/procmail.log
SHELL=/bin/sh
msgID=""
errorMSG="Error."

:0
* (r|R)@domain.com

:0fw
* ^Content-Transfer-Encoding:.*base64 | mmencode -u -b

{
:0B
* ^()\/[a-z]+[0-9]+
{ msgID = "$MATCH" }

result=`mysql -uxxx -pxxx -e "select data from table1 where id='"$msgID"'`
```

....

Comment: mmencode is no longer available.  base 64 decoding is now part of the core utilities. Use `base64 --decode` instead of the `mmencode -u -b`.

Comment: For matching try without the dot in front of the *.  `^Content-Transfer-Encoding: *base64`.  So the whole line would be: `* ^Content-Transfer-Encoding: *base64 | base64 --decode`

Comment: What does the message which you expect to match look like? Please [edit] the question to include a (small but useful) sample.

Comment: The `DEFAULT` assignment looks fishy, too. Do you really have privileges to write new files in `/var/mail`; and even if you do, why would you want to?

Answer (score 2):

The `| mmencode -u -b` is in the wrong place. You have made it part of the regex you are trying to  match -- of course it won't.

You probably mean

```
:0fw
* r@domain\.com
* ^Content-Transfer-Encoding:.*base64
| mmencode -u -b
```

or possibly

```
:0
* r@domain\.com
{
    :0fw
    * ^Content-Transfer-Encoding:.*base64
    | mmencode -u -b
#...
}
```

The general form of a Procmail  recipe is

```
:0flags
* conditions
action
```

where you can omit the conditions to make a recipe unconditional; but the action is mandatory. You cannot leave it out.

If you change the content encoding, you  should also update the corresponding MIME headers (unless you are ditching this message once you are done with it, of course).

Notice also how the `(r|R)` alternation is unnecessary, because Procmail matches case-insensitively by default.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't format a new line in the comments.  Thanks for clearing that up.  Also, the mmencode won't be available if they are using any OS newer than 2008...

Comment: I hardly think that's central to the question. If the OP used this command, I assume it's available to them. The pointer to `base64` is useful  going forward, of course.

Comment: @arikin FWIW base64 -d can be used to decode the message body instead of mmencode.  The base64 command, which comes with the coreutils package, should be available on all modern linux systems.

Comment: `base64` can handle an individual MIME part, but not an entire message.  You will need to add some wrapper script to isolate the part you want to decode.